How to manage data with Python/Jython script in apache hop like Pandas?
I'm working in a pipeline in Apache hop so i want to manage data as similar way i can do with Pandas in Python. The problem is that the script block doesn't receive a csv so I don't know how I can manipulate and transformate data (applying algorithm). On of the first impediments is that i receive columns(not csv to read) in the script block and other impediment is that it uses Jython instead of Python. Here i can add a varible
But I would like todo something like this...
I have tried to import Pandas but it doesn't work because it uses Jython

Jython is based on Python 2.x if I am not wrong. I think you can install an older pandas version that was working for python 2.x. Perhaps pandas 0.2.x could do the trick but better check yourself. As for the CSV filename, it is totally dependent on the environmentyou are using. Not much help here...

The problem is that Pandas doesn't work in any version of Jython. And the other problem is more related with hop functionality because in the block i'm receiving the columns and i don't know how to manage that...please see the images before comment or answer...

Yes you have point with pandas, I forgot that numpy should also be compiled with Jythno, which is not the case. Honestly the images are not super descriptive and your post could have included the images right away. Anyhow, this now becomes an issue of apache hop and don't know if you can at least get the data passed to you as input stream. Then you could perhaps parse them with the help of the built-in csv module, but this still is a longshot, I 'm afraid.
